# Placing UIView or UILabel inside UITextField or UITextView acting like character

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I need to create a dialog, similar to the one that is used to write functions in Numbers from APple, for example.

User can select range in the table, which is then represented as any kind of UIView inside text input line. When long-tapped, the content can be edited like normal text, but what is most important is that whole subView, containing text with range description is treated as one character.

Does anybody know or have idea how to achieve this?

I would appreciate any hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to deal with something similar, to have custom UIView(s) in a search field.

I'm not aware of a "simple" way (ie, API) to achieve your goal. You need to create a custom component that looks like a classic field, but isn't one.

To be a little more specific:

- Subclass an UIView (or directly an UIScrollView)
- Have inside a TextField (or UITextView depending if it needs more than one line) to handle the "keyboard".
- Put some custom UIView/UILabel before the textField/textView and adjust the textField/textView origin depending these views/labels

If you want to have a label/view IN the text, then it's a little more complex and you'll need something even more custom:

- Handling the keyboard events without a textField/textView (there is a way but I forgot how exactly)
- Drawing the text and adding views/labels in specific locations.

Of course all depends on the component you want to create ^^ there is no one simple answer.

Comment: Well, development of full featured editor, like the one available from Omnigroup Framework is one solution, but is actually overkill for some single line expression edit. THe second choice is to play with tabs and insert Labels in Tab places similar to what you have suggested...However, I wondered it there is some better solution available, since embedding graphics inside UITextView is not possible...Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you find a better solution, let me know :)

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking of dumping UITextView and rather employ set of UILabels that are replaced by UITextField on long press and after edit replaced back to UILabel...

Comment: That's a bit harsh, but why not. So consider drawing the text & co directly in a drawRect.

Comment: Not really, this must be the easiest way. You don't need to draw text, since UILabel has text property that can be formatted as well.